# Admob advertisement seems like background

Tags: android

The advertisement is visible but it is not clickable and it looks as background image.
What is the problem ? is this about xml or java code ?
Here is xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
tools:context=".Search">

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.ads.AdView 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="MY - ID"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:scrollingCache="false">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is java

```
    RelativeLayout RelativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
AdView adView=new AdView(this,AdSize.SMART_BANNER,"MY - ID");
    RelativeLayout1.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your XML Layout, you are using a RelativeLayout and adding two components on the same RelativeLayout, if you want to prevent the content to be overlap you need to set that on the layout adding something like:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
```

to the ListView , or you can use a LinearLayout, but I don't know how you want your layout...if you draw the layout I can try to help

Comment: i added this code android:layout_above="@+id/adView and it's okey.
Thank you so much.